# How do we click a button that is not an element in the HTML code in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I'm trying to click the button "ok" in this image:
[image: image with popup reading "First name must be in English letters only" with blue "OK" button]

I want to click the button "ok" in this image,
this button is not an element in the HTML code so I cannot locate it by anything.

This is a pop up as a result of making an error in the registration process on some websites.

Can anyone please help? And if there's a solution, can you tell me where to put it exactly in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()

'''
this is the answer
'''

Answer (score 0):

The button has to be a element. Did you double check that maybe the entire text box has a click function that you can access?

Comment: yes i checked, it is not an element at all

Comment: you can't select it from DevTools. it seems as if it's from outside of the code

Comment: Element has to come from somewhere. Press ctrl f on the source code and try to find the text of the element.

Comment: from my search, i understood that it is an alert, not an element. i looked up solutions online and even the one i found for alerts did not work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to click ok in the alert. There are standard tools for this in selenium.

```
# Click the link to activate the alert
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "See an example alert").click()

# Wait for the alert to be displayed and store it in a variable
alert = wait.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())

# Store the alert text in a variable
text = alert.text

# Press the OK button
alert.accept()
```

Check this for additional info: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/alerts/

Comment: i understand but i have no idea how to match this sample with my code. i tried copying this into my code and it did not work